# Too frequent load of Quartz Scheduler in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, config, quartz-scheduler

I am writing a Spring application and I use Quart Scheduler.

I'm running Jetty server and everything is ok, my app works:

[image]

I am sending an HTTP request to the one of my services and then, everything is refreshing:

[image]

and Quartz gives this log 3 times:
[image]

Here is a piece of my config.xml file:

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="fileimport" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="${prop.checkinterval}" />

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="fileimport" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How can I load context once, during startup, and use it later without refreshing?

Comment: could you tell me how you fixed your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the context is reload each time when you load your XML file. Try to create different XML files for each Java Class and then, load each of them just once.

You can use it us a private static field of your class.